# Displaying accented characters correctly in html, php mail and text

Tags: php, html, email, export-to-csv

I have an HTML5 form collecting personal data. The output from the form is passed to a php/HTML file which does three things with it.

1. It creates and displays a new HTML5 table re-displaying all of the received data for visual confirmation.
2. It creates and sends an email (using the PHP `mail()` function) with some of the input data.
3. It uses all of the input data to create and add a line to a text (csv) file.

HTML5 files all use `<html lang="en">` and `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

My problem is that everything works nicely – until an accented character is input into the initial form. Say ö, É or something like that – as happens with the occasional person’s name. Whilst such characters display properly in the HTML confirmation table, they become garbled in the email and the csv file – typically ö becomes Ã¶.

I have searched through other similar questions and their answers, but find nothing that provides satisfactory answers – especially the part regarding the creation of a text file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the email sent and the CSV generated/opened?

Comment: Hi chris85. The email is sent using php's mail() function. The text file is created with the php fwrite() function.

Comment: for `mail()` there is a fourth parameter in the function where you can set headers. for `fwrite()` you have have to set the UTF-8 BOM in the file header (namely `\xEF\xBB\xBF`)

Comment: Thanks David Pilkington. I explore your suggestions. Much appreciated.

Comment: We need more information about how you're emailing and the headers being aent

Comment: @BarryDowns did you come right?

Comment: Not yet - haven't had time to experiment! Hopefully shortly. Thank you for your help and interest.